# Verification of the maximum number of pairwise non-disjoint subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,100\}$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, problem-solving

Let $A=\{1,2,\cdots ,100\}$. Let $S$ be some set of subsets of $A$ such that any two elements of $S$ have a nonempty intersection. Then what is the maximum possible cardinality of $S$?

**My answer**- My intuition is that all the subsets must have one element in common, so if I consider the element the element $1$, then the sets {$1$},{$1$,any one among 99 other elements},{$1$, any one among 99 other elements, any one among 98 other elements} $,\cdots$ until the original set $A$. This can be done in ${99}\choose_0$ + ${99}\choose_{1}$ + $\cdots$ + $99\choose_{99}$ ways which is $2^{99}$. Please can anyone verify the way I have solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: This problem is solved in this website but the proper detailed solution was not given that is why I have written a solution of the given problem to check whether my method is completely right or not. Thank you.

Comment: You have not proved that this is the maximum. Though you've demonstrated a lower bound for the maximum. Please also link the source of the problem since you have it. (Also to nitpick the terminology, it should be "nonempty intersection" not "nonzero intersection")

Comment: Possibly https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573607/s-be-a-collection-of-subsets-of-1-100-any-two-sets-in-s-has-non

Comment: You have shown the maximum is at least half of the power set.  By pairing subsets of $A$ and their complements (which do not intersect), you can show it cannot be more than half (all this assuming $A$ is not empty).

Comment: I am sorry coul you show the proof @Henry.

Comment: The pigeonhole principle argument given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1581939/473276) is a nice way to prove the upper bound. Can you say what details you think are missing from this answer and Henry's link that makes them not a proper detailed solution? Is your objection that they haven't written out a sum of $100$ binomial coefficients?

Comment: Yes , something like that, @IzaakvanDongen. Also the the proof you have referred to , I don’t understand why do we have to check that there will be more elements because if the least cardinality of any intersection will be $1$, so taking  any single element subset should maximise the set $S$.

Comment: The fact that any two sets have a nonempty intersection doesn't immediately imply that all the sets together have a nonempty intersection. Consider for example $\{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}$. So there is definitely an argument required to check there are no bigger families of subsets.

Comment: Oh , now I get it, thank you very much @IzaakvanDongen